# Using a convolutional net to predict live breakouts based on a numeric feature

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, probability

Say I have a feature X that measures the number of people with some rare contagious virus in a population. X is reported at the end of each day by a government agency that monitors disease outbreaks. Suppose I also had a ton of past values of X grouped into 20 day chunks. So each group has 20 entries of X, representing the number of infected people on each of the given 20 days.

These groups of past data were then labeled:

1. Normal - the 20 day period showed totally normal values for X and there was not threat of a breakout in them.
2. Breakout - the 20 day period showed a breakout where the value of X went up above normal levels and then rapidly got worse.
3. False breakout - the 20 day period showed a false breakout where the value of X raised slightly but then dropped back to normal levels.

I would then like to use this data to train a model that could then be applied to a new breakout that is happening live to predict at any instance during the breakout the probability that it was going to be a real breakout or a false breakout. The only feature that I want this model to consider, for better or for worse, is the values for X.

Now I believe that in some way I could apply a convolutional layer to this network that can explore the feature/behavior of X that predict false breakouts VS real breakouts. I think this is possible because of how convolutional nets are used in image classification and applied to this problem it seems I could take the burden off of me as the  algorithm creator to find ways in which X acts during false breakouts V real breakouts

I think this is an interesting application of a convolutional network and was wondering if anyone had any insight into how something like this could be approached?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if you have only 20 values for each "example" to train your classification network, a CNN could be an overkill and probably also ineffective for the really small amount of input data it can analyze. Remember that a CNN works using kernels that progressively scans and convolve regions of data searching for patterns representation, and in my opinion you don't have enough data for that. Standard kernels for CNNs are around 3x3 or 5x5.

I think you're probably best off with a standard Neural Network with an input layer of dimension 20, an hidden layer of something around 64-128 neurons and an output layer of 3 classes (Normal, Breakout, False).
Activations would be ReLu and a final Softmax to obtain percentages.

A different case would be if you'd want to correlate blocks of 20 days taken in different countries, as an example. In that case you could create a sort of "image" with each column as the 20 days values of each country/place and training a CNN that way.